# Filter Categories based on user Permissions

Tags: permissions, office-365, office, community-site

We have a community site. On the home page we have listed all the available Categories.

Is there any way that we can filter the Categories on the Home Page to only show categories  that the user has Permissions for.

Thank you,
Richards.

Comment: How are you displaying the categories? Which webpart are you using for that?

Comment: In the form of promoted links (default option). We have directly inserted categories list on the home page. In the options i see we can filter based on User Permissions, but not sure how to apply it. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below

1. Go to your Promoted Links List.
2. From the Ribbon select "List" and change the view to "All Promoted Links" Instead of default "Tile". This should change your list to regular list instead of showing Tile.
3. Now select one Item from the list.
4. While you item select, from the Ribbon select "Item" and click "Shared With".
5. Click Advanced on the Shared With dialogue.
6. This will take you to item level permission screen. Change the inheritance and assign unique permission there.
7. Perform this for any items that you want to have unique permission.

Now Promoted links web part will automatically show links as per the logged-in user permission.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c70e92e0-f49e-4953-a200-de2d82fe4d2e/controlling-visibility-of-links-in-a-promoted-links-list?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thank you Amal. I will try this and will keep you posted with the output.

Comment: We have the permissions correctly set at each category level, the challenge is, we have displayed all the categories in the form of promoted links in the HOME page, so all the user will also have read access to the HOME page and all the users are able to see the entire list of categories. is it because of the conflict in permissions. Do we have a workaround. Please advise. Thank you.